# Remote MySQL Connection for a range IPs

Tags: mysql

I am tring to setup a remote mysql user that can access mysql from IPs (192.168.1.100~192.168.1.255).

I tried the following command:

```
GRANT select ON *.* TO 'uname'@'192.168.1.%'  IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

The problem is it allows IPs from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.99 too.

So I tried this one:

```
GRANT select ON *.* TO 'uname'@'192.168.1.100/25'  IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Same result. Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GRANT select ON . TO 'uname'@'192.168.1.1__' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT select ON . TO 'uname'@'192.168.1.2__' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```